# TCP handshake phases corresponding to select() and accept() return points

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP server that creates a (blocking) socket, waits until it is available for reading using select(), then calls accept() and starts reading the data.
Here is an [example](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/selectserver.c) (not mine) illustrating the concept.

The question is, at what points of TCP handshake does select() and accept() calls return?

[image: TCP 3-way handshake]

Ubuntu Hardy, if it matters.
2.6.31-14-server #48ya1 SMP Fri Apr 2 15:43:25 MSD 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select()` returns, indicating that the listening socket is "readable", immediately after the last packet in that diagram is recieved.

If you had blocked on `accept()` instead, it would have returned at that same point (when the server socket transitions to ESTABLISHED).